# Move a rectangle when a key is pressed

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I need the loop() method to be able to run repaint() but it does nothing when it's called.

Moreover, the loop() method also doesn't update() when executing the code. I've tried many different variations to try and get it to work but nothing has worked. In addition to that, I use the IDE Eclipse because my teacher said we shouldn't use game engines but write the code from scratch.

class:GamePanel

```java
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    final int originalTilesize=16;
    final int scale=3;
    final int tileSize=originalTilesize *scale;
    final int maxScreenRow=12;
    final int maxScreenCol=16;
    final int screenWidth=tileSize*maxScreenCol;
    final int screenHeight=tileSize*maxScreenRow;
    
    int FPS=60;
    KeyHandler keyH = new KeyHandler(); // implements KeyHandler in GamePanel
    Thread gameThread;

    int playerX=100;
    int playerY=100;
    int playerSpeed=4;

    public GamePanel()
    {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth,screenHeight));
        this.setBackground(Color.black);
        this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        this.addKeyListener(keyH);
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }
    public void startGameThread()
    {
        gameThread = new Thread(this);  
        gameThread.start();
    }


    public void run() {
        double drawInterval=1000000000/FPS;
        double nextDrawTime=System.nanoTime()+drawInterval;// TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (gameThread !=null) {
            update();
            repaint();
            
            try {
                double remainingTime=nextDrawTime-System.nanoTime();
                remainingTime=remainingTime/1000000;
                if (remainingTime<0)
                {
                    remainingTime=0;
                }
                Thread.sleep((long)remainingTime);
                nextDrawTime+=drawInterval;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };  
    }

    public void update()
    {
        if (keyH.upPressed == true)
        {
            playerY-=playerSpeed;
        }
        else if(keyH.downPressed==true)
        {
            playerY +=playerSpeed;  
        }
        else if(keyH.leftPressed==true)
        {
            playerX -=playerSpeed;  
        }
        else if(keyH.rightPressed==true)
        {
            playerX +=playerSpeed;  
        }
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setColor(Color.white);
        g2.fillRect(playerX,playerY,tileSize,tileSize);
        g2.dispose();
    }
}
```

class:KeyListener

```java
package main;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
public class KeyHandler implements KeyListener {
    public boolean upPressed,downPressed,leftPressed,rightPressed;

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        
        int code =e.getKeyCode();
        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upPressed = true;   
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downPressed=true;   
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        leftPressed=true;
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightPressed=true;  
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int code=e.getKeyCode();
        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            upPressed = false;  
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            downPressed=false;  
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            leftPressed=false;
        }

        if (code==KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            rightPressed=false; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add a few System.out.println statements to see which parts of your code get executed or what variable values they are facing. An even better approach would be to start debugging your code: https://www.baeldung.com/eclipse-debugging

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a "game loop" that redraws the GUI every few seconds. You just need to call method [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). Also, it is not recommended to call method `repaint` from a thread which is **not** the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) (EDT). Lastly, you should use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html).

The below code is not a complete solution. It just sets up a key binding for the down-arrow key which moves the rectangle down when the user presses the down-arrow key. Note that you also need to handle the situation when the rectangle hits the edge of the `GamePanel` – unless you **want** to draw the rectangle at such a location that it doesn't appear in the `GamePanel`.

(More notes after the code.)

```java
package main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    final int originalTilesize = 16;
    final int scale = 3;
    final int tileSize = originalTilesize * scale;
    final int maxScreenRow = 12;
    final int maxScreenCol = 16;
    final int screenWidth = tileSize * maxScreenCol;
    final int screenHeight = tileSize * maxScreenRow;

    int playerX = 100;
    int playerY = 100;
    int playerSpeed = 4;

    public GamePanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        setBackground(Color.black);
        setFocusable(true);
        InputMap im = getInputMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "DOWN");
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        am.put("DOWN", new DownAction());
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillRect(playerX, playerY, tileSize, tileSize);
        g.dispose();
    }

    class DownAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerY += playerSpeed;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.add(new GamePanel());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

- This line is not required as it is the default.

```java
this.setDoubleBuffered(true);
```

- Method `startGameThread` is not required (as explained above) and should therefore be removed. Consequently, method `run` should also be removed which means that class `GamePanel` does **not** need to implement interface `Runnable`. Also no need for variables `FPS` and `gameThread`.
- As shown in above code, you need to write an `Action` for each key binding which therefore replaces method `update` so that method can also be removed. In the above code, I have created one `Action`, named `DownAction`. You need to create an `Action` for the other arrow keys. The keystroke names are:

  - UP
  - RIGHT
  - LEFT
- Since we are using key bindings, no need for class `KeyHandler` nor for variable `keyH`.
- Method `paintComponent` has `protected` access so no need to make it `public`.
- In method `paintComponent` you are only calling methods of class `Graphics` so no need for the cast.
- I added a `main` method so that the above code is a runnable application.